# password confirmation error messaage on password_confirmation field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, client-side-validation, devise-confirmable

I have my user models validation for password confirmation like this

```
validate_confirmation_of :password
```

This add the error message `doesn't match` to the password field, but I need this error message on the password_confirmation field.

Can this be achieved in any other way.? I need this because, I use client side validations to show errors in form and I want this error to appear on the password_confirmation field rather than on the password field.

Comment: hey vishnu, did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple custom validation:

```
class User
  validate :password_confirmation_matches_password

  def password_confirmation_matches_password
    if password != password_confirmation
      errors.add(:password_confirmation, "isn't the same")
    end
  end
end
```